# Problem with understanding some of learning objectives of ISTQB Advanced Level - Technical Test Analyst

Tags: test-management, istqb

I'm preparing myself to exam of ISTQB Advanced Level - Technical Test Analyst. I've just finished the chapter and after that I still can't answer on questions asked on the beginning of it. I.e. I'm not sure about my answers.

So, I'd like to ask you to verify my responses:

> 1. Explain the stages in an application's lifecycle where non-functional tests and architecture based-test tests may be applied.
>      Explain the causes of non-functional testing taking place only in
>      specific stages of application's lifecycle.

Non-functional tests can be applied in any stage of an application's lifecycle. Some of non-functional characteristic like efficiency depends of quality of a single components. Therefore execution efficiency should be already tested at the unit or integration level.

Some non-functional testing does not have sense until late in the Software Development Life Cycle. It is not possible to measure a characteristic like usability before the product is not integrated into one system.

(I don't understand what does *architecture based-test tests* mean. Can someone explain this term for me?)

> 2. Give examples of the criteria that influence the structure and level of test condition development

- If you have a marketing requirements document and a system requirements document then you can use the former to generate high-level test conditions and then use the latter to elaborate same low-level test conditions underneath each high-level one.
- Quality risk analyst - we can outline the key features and quality characteristics at a high level. These quality risk items are thus the test high-level test conditions

> 3. Describe how test analysis and design are static testing techniques that can be used to discover defects.

The process of test analysis and design needs to precise understanding the requirements specification, design specification, or other documents used as input into process. It allows identify defects in the documentation.

> 4. Explain by giving examples the concept of the test oracle and how a test oracle can be used in test specifications

To be honest, I don't understand this exercise. How the test oracle can be used to test a specifications? English is not my native language, it is a problem.

Comment: This is 4 separate question.  People my have answer(s) for 1 or 2 or 3 of them but we can't vote and comment on them appropriately because you have 4 questions within 1 question.  The site is designed for specific single questions that will have a single answer that we can vote on.  Please break your questions up.

Comment: I see the point, but it doesn't have sense to split these questions because they are connected each other. All of them are about ISTQB, preparation to the exam and concern the same chapter/subject. In my opinion it would be confusing to break the questions up.

Comment: I respect your opinion and I understand it would be hard to break the question up due to the dependencies.  However you could try and at least make some progress in doing it.  Your reason is valid but it isn't how the site works.  If you can't break it up please consider that the complex question may simply not fit our Q&A format on this site.  I'm saying all this because we want to help but I doubt you'll get the help you need as is.  Hopefully I'm wrong and someone else will tacke it all.